# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: plexus.container.default: Invalid module name: 'default' is not a Java identifier

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, javafx

I've this issue when I'm trying to launch my jar with a script bash:

**Complete issue :**

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for C:\Users\aposk\Desktop\Twitter_App_Win_Version\app\ressources\lib\plexus-container-default-1.0-alpha-9-stable-1.jar

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: plexus.container.default: Invalid module name: 'default' is not a Java identifier
```

**script bash**

```html
@echo off

::apt-get install openjfx
SET JAVA_HOME=C:\Users\aposk\Desktop\Twitter_App_Win_Version\jdk-13.0.1
SET PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
java -version

java -jar --module-path "C:\Users\aposk\Desktop\Twitter_App_Win_Version\app\ressources\lib" --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml "C:\Users\aposk\Desktop\Twitter_App_Win_Version\app\ressources\pip-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"

pause
```

We are working on JDK 13 but works on JDK too --> cause of Http request by import of java.net.

I'm on Win-64bits et works on eclipse with maven. Others solutions on web didn't fix my issue

Comment: One of the JAR is not ready to be used in [JPMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System). So either use the classpath instead of the modulepath or rename the JAR (since in this case the invalid module name is derived from the file name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back with solution!

If you need ton run your .jar with JFX a newer version than JAVA 8, you need to set up your system with the jdk, but also you need to create a new main class without extend on APplication. In this class you'll run your mainApp with a public void method and you need to add some arguments in you pom.xml (feg)

```html
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
    <executions>
     <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
       <goal>shade</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
       <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
       <shadedClassifierName>project/classifier</shadedClassifierName>
       <outputFile>shade\${project.artifactId}.jar</outputFile>
       <transformers>
        <transformer
         implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
         <mainClass>fr.tse.fise2.pip.graphic.Main</mainClass>
        </transformer>
       </transformers>
      </configuration>
     </execution>
    </executions>
```

You also need do configure some module for java fx in you pom.xml

```html
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
   <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
   <version>13</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
   <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
   <version>13</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
   <artifactId>javafx-graphics </artifactId>
   <version>13</version>
   <classifier>mac</classifier>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
   <artifactId>javafx-graphics </artifactId>
   <version>13</version>
   <classifier>linux</classifier>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
   <artifactId>javafx-graphics </artifactId>
   <version>13</version>
   <classifier>win</classifier>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
   <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
   <version>13</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
   <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
   <version>13</version>
  </dependency>
    
     <dependency>
   <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
   <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
   <version>13</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-fxml -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
   <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
   <version>13</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jfoenix/jfoenix -->
  <dependency>
```

Now you can run you jar with cmd java -jar filename.jar at the correct location of your jar

My projects works with JavaFx and JAVA 11

Helped by Kamil